# How can i set the incoming buffer size for datagram packets in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: networking, emacs, elisp

I'm writing a simple networking application in elisp that uses `make-network-process` to open a listening socket. i'm listening for udp (SOCK_DGRAM) packets, and using wireshark I can see on the network that my packets are 199 bytes long. however, the process filter in emacs returns a string that is only 195 bytes long! is there a buffer size i need to set somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball is suggesting that what you think are 195 *bytes* are really 195 *chars* that were represented as 199 bytes on the wire because of DOS-style CR/LF line-ends or utf-8 encoding or something like that.

Comment: I used `string-as-unibyte` before parsing my udp packet, and it worked! thanks!

Comment: Don't: `string-as-unibyte` is a gross hack that will never *really* do what you want (tho it will often accidentally do something close enough).  Instead, you want to specify the coding-system (e.g. `binary`) that your process should use, e.g. via `set-process-coding-system` or `coding-system-for-read`.

Comment: thanks @Stefan! i just found the `:coding` argument to make-network-process. set `'binary` there and everything's working!